# Using hsv curve in timeline

Tags: animation, bezier-curves, keyframes

I'm trying to modify the color of an object depending to the time. I set keyframe with the colors and I see the RGB curves in the timeline :

[image]

Is it possible to have HSV curves instead of RGB curves to deal more easily with hue, saturation and value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use the HSV space by adding the Combine_HSV node as input color to you material, then keyframe its values  :

to keyframe a value <kbd>RMB</kbd> on the value in the **Node Editor**  and click ***Insert Keyframe***

[image]

F-curves :

[image]

example file : [image]

Comment: I tried to use shader nodes to set this graph on the material but I can't keyframe colors anymore. Could you be a bit more precise on the sequence to execute ?

Comment: You can also press the 'i' key while hovering over various fields and colors to set keyframes.  I just tried this on the Diffuse Material Node Color Preview square,  and the keyframe was correctly set.  I tested the color's animation with cycles viewport rendering and it works fine.